# MySQL GIS - GeomFromText error

Tags: mysql, gis, point

I have a table with a Decimal degrees (-22.541100,30.719333) field. I altered the table and added a spatial data column (POINT) to the table. I am trying to update the POINT field with the point value of the Decimal degrees field but cannot get it to work.

**This is my sql**:

```
SELECT @loc:= REPLACE(coordinates, ',', ' ') FROM interventions;

UPDATE interventions SET location = GeomFromText('POINT('@loc')');
```

**I keep on getting an error**: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@loc')')' at line 1

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post some data from your table ? the question not so clear

Comment: Use: `... GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', @loc, ')'));`.

Comment: Thank you wchiquito. GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', @loc, ')')); worked!